# How do I access ScreenManager commands through the main.py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So I'm making an app using Kivy. One of my screens have buttons that are indeterminate in number so they are added through the main.py file using a for loop. My code goes something like this:

```
class CategWin(Screen):
    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self, **kwargs):
        for i in range(10):
            button = Button(text="B_" + str(i),
                            color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                            background_normal="button1.png",
                            background_down="button2.png")
            self.ids.menu.add_widget(button)

class ChannelWin(Screen):
    ***some code***
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

The first class has the mentioned function. In a kv file, you can use

```
on_release:
    app.root.current = "screen_name"
    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

to assign switch screen commands but how do you do it through the main.py file?

I also tried the `switch_to()` function mentioned in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.builder.html) but it returns this error.

```
##Code:
button.bind(on_press=WindowManager.switch_to(ChannelWin))
```

```
TypeError: switch_to() missing 1 required positional argument: 'screen'
```

I'm pretty new to kivy so I'm lost. I also can't find any solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class CategWin(Screen):
    @mainthread
    def on_enter(self, **kwargs):
        for i in range(10):
            button = Button(text="B_" + str(i),
                            color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                            background_normal="button1.png",
                            background_down="button2.png")
            button.bind(on_press=self.go_to_Channelwin)
            self.ids.menu.add_widget(button)

    def go_to_Channelwin(self, pressed_button):
        self.manager.current = "ChannelWin_screen_name"
```

Where `ChannelWin_screen_name` is replaced by whatever `name` you have assigned to the `ChannelWin` instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your callback definition, instead of using the `WindowManager.switch_to` function, you could use python's built-in function with `WindowManager.current` attribute.

`setattr(WindowManager,'current','screen_name')`

Comment: I forgot. You could wrap the bind callback function in a lambda function to deal with any passed variable. i.e. ```lambda *a: setattr(...)```